# How to get the client device details which is connected to Mobile Hotspot and WiFi

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on an application and I need to show the Mobile Hotspot and Wifi connected device detail like Device Name, Ip Address and Mac Address. I have applied some solution and also check some github project,
But still not getting the device details in current OS.
Please suggest me how can I get the device details.
Thanks in Advance.

I have tried this solution git hub project(http://rorist.github.com/android-network-discovery),
fetch device detail using Jetpack Compose and also try to fetch using the path "/proc/net/arp" but in latest OS i'm getting permission issue.

Comment: Can you share more specific details of what you tried and the error messages you received?

Comment: Thanks for help, I've enabled Mobile Hotspot in my android phone and 2 other android phones are connected to my Hotspot, then how can I get the details of those connected devices like Device name, IP address, Device Mac-Address.
Can you please suggest that is it possible or is there any other way?